# Property is null causing NullReferenceException but Primary and Foreign keys in Entity Framework database are correct and perfectly match each other

Tags: mysql, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

NOTE: Because IDs in database look perfect it might be just mistake in my razor view when I try to refer to property of the model's property (it is in the end of the post). I am weak at LINQ.

---

I have a `class Person` in `Models.Person.cs` it has reference to Surveys:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // MANY PROPERTIES BEETWEEN
        [DisplayName("Surveys")]
        public virtual ICollection<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and I got `class Survey` which consists of `Question`s and Every `Question` has an `Answer.
These classes are in`Models.Survey.cs` and look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public class Question {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string QuestionText { set; get; }
        public  ICollection<Answer> Answers { set; get; }
        public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; }
        public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
    }
    public class Answer {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string AnswerText { set; get; }
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    }
    public class Survey {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public ICollection<Question> Questions { set; get; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**The Entity Framework database context class looks like:**

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {


        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CONSTRUCTOR");

        }

        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create() {

            return new ApplicationDbContext();

        }
    }
```

**I seed the database:**

```
  protected override void Seed(WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext context) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SEED STARTED");
            var survey = new Survey() { Questions = new List<Question>() };
            if (!context.Surveys.Any()) {


                //the below is hardcoded for DEMO. you may get the data from some  
                //other place and set the questions and answers

                var q1 = new Question() { QuestionText = "What is your favourite language", Answers = new List<Answer>() };
                Answer a1 = new Answer() { AnswerText = "PHP" };
                Answer a2 = new Answer() { AnswerText = "ASP.NET" };
                Answer a3 = new Answer() { AnswerText = "Java" };
                context.Answers.AddOrUpdate(a1);
                context.Answers.AddOrUpdate(a2);
                context.Answers.AddOrUpdate(a3);
                context.Questions.AddOrUpdate(q1);

                q1.Answers.Add(a1);
                q1.Answers.Add(a2);
                q1.Answers.Add(a3);
                survey.Questions.Add(q1);

                var q2 = new Question() { QuestionText = "What is your favourite DB", Answers = new List<Answer>() };
                a1 = new Answer() { AnswerText = "SQL Server" };
                a2 = new Answer() { AnswerText = "MySQL" };
                a3 = new Answer() { AnswerText = "Oracle" };
                q2.Answers.Add(a1);
                q2.Answers.Add(a2);
                q2.Answers.Add(a3);

                context.Answers.AddOrUpdate(a1);
                context.Answers.AddOrUpdate(a2);
                context.Answers.AddOrUpdate(a3);
                context.Questions.AddOrUpdate(q2);

                survey.Questions.Add(q2);

                context.Surveys.AddOrUpdate(survey);
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
            if (!context.Persons.Any()) {
                var persons = new List<Person> { 
                         new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "123-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "312312312", Notes = "Annoying", Surveys = new List<Survey>(){survey}},
                         new Person{FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "113-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "548555672", Notes = "Less Annoying", Surveys = new List<Survey>()}
                        };


                persons.ForEach(person => context.Persons.AddOrUpdate(person));
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
}
```

---

The produced database **looks very good**. We can see that Survey(Id=4) is associated with John Doe(Id=6) and that Questions(Id=7,8) are associated with Survey(Id=4) etc. so **it looks brilliant.**

[image]

**BUT THEN** if I try to display(in Razor View) number of surveys for John Doe(Id = 6) I get 1 which is correct and then number of questions in this survey ( by`@Html.DisplayFor(x => survey.Questions.Count`)  I get `A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll` and nothing is displayed.

**The view:**

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Person
<hr />
<h2>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surveys)</h2>

<input type="button" id="Coll" value="Collapse" onclick="javascript:CollapseDiv()" />
<p>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Surveys.Count)
</p>
@foreach (var survey in Model.Surveys) {
    <p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm()) {

            <text>ANK</text>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => survey.Questions.Count)   //HERE I GET NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
            <input type="submit" />
        }
    </p>
}

<hr />
```

THE RESULT:

[image]

EDIT:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(p => p.Answers).WithMany(a => a.Persons);   
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }`
```

Comment: it will be nice to see how is the model object filled with data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding virtual keyword on `Questions` collection. This will enable lazy loading as long as the context is still alive. You might need to add it to `Answers` collection too.

```
public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { set; get; }
```

Or you can use eager loading.

```
var model = db.Persons.
    Include(p => p.Questions).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == xx);
```

**PS**

There are few ways you can load navigation properties.

- Lazy Loading

  Required

  - `virtual` keyword on the navigation property
  - Enable lazy loading, `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;`
  - Enable proxy, `db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;`
  - `DbContext` not disposed, if it's disposed, the object disposed exception will be thrown
  - -

  The related navigation  will be loaded only when there is any access to the property. For example:

  ```
  // Questions is not loaded yet.
  var person = db.Persons.FirstOrDefault();
  // Questions will be loaded.
  var questions = person.Questions;
  // Questions will be loaded even though you only ask for the count.
  var qCount = person.Questions.Count;
  ```
- Eager Loading

  Required

  - `Include` method
  - -

  This will load the navigation property as part of the main query using join statement in the generated query.

  ```
  // Questions will be loaded together with the main query.
  var person = db.Persons.Include(p => p.Questions).FirstOrDefault();
  ```
- Explicit Loading

  Required

  - `db.Entry(entity).Reference(/* reference */).Load();` method
  - `db.Entry(entity).Collection(/* collection */).Load();` method
  - `DbContext`
  - -

  This will load each navigation property explicitly.

  ```
  // Loads the main entity first.
  var person = db.Persons.FirstOrDefault();
  // Explicitly load the Questions.
  db.Entry(person).Collection(p => p.Questions).Load();
  ```

  Additionally you can filter the `Questions` if necessary.

  ```
  db.Entry(person)
     .Collection(p => p.Questions)
     .Query() 
     .Where(q => q.QuestionText.Contains("Entity Framework"))
     .Load();
  ```
- Relationship Fixup

  Required

  - `Select` clause for each navigation property in the anonymous type
  - -

  This will automatically link the main entity and navigation property and can also be used to filter the navigation property. The generated query will produce join statement.

  ```
  var person = db.Persons.Select(p => new
  {
      Person = p,
      Questions = p.Questions
          .Where(q => q.QuestionText.Contains("Entity Framework"))
  }).AsEnumerable().Select(t => t.Person).FirstOrDefault();
  ```

  Above query selects the `Person` and the `Questions` into anonymous type on the first `Select` clause then converts it to enumerable (deferred execution) and then the second `Select` clause only selects the `Person` property, but the result will link the `Questions` property to each `Person`. And finally the query is executed by `FirstOrDefault` method.

Without any of above method the navigation property will not be loaded automatically.

More:

- [Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: Adding virtual helped. Could you please elaborate why it didn't just load it without it and do I need change something in my OnModelCreating? I posted it in edit to OP. I will have many to many relationship between Person and Answer.